# gnuplot: inconsistent colors in columnstacked histogram with column title and key

Tags: colors, gnuplot, histogram

I minified my problem as follows:

```
reset
unset output
set terminal wxt

set style histogram columnstacked 
set style data histogram 

plot  "deletions.stat"  using 2:key(1) ti col , "" using 3 ti col

#deletions.stat
#Number One Two
#Stack1 2 4
#Stack2 3 6
```

What I get is:

[image]

Obviously, the key for Stack1 should be green - not red.

I am missing something or is this a bug?

Note: Leaving out ":key(1)" solves this problem as the key is not shown any more. Another solution is leaving out both instances of "to col", but I need them there.

Comment: Thanks! I am using 4.6 patchlevel 0. I will try to update immediately!

In the meantime, I found a workaround to solve this issue:
Insert a dummy column in your data file which you do not have to use later on:

    reset
    unset output
    set terminal wxt
    
    set style histogram columnstacked 
    set style data histogram 
    
    set key autotitle columnheader
    plot  "deletions.stat" using 3:key(1) , "" using 4
    
    #deletions.stat
    #Number DUMMY Two Three
    #Stack1 0 2 4
    #Stack2 0 3 6

The result looks just as expected: http://snag.gy/PFi8a.jpg

Comment: Running 4.6.3 now.
It works better, however, there is still an issue if you leave out "ti col". But inserting it, it works fine. One can also insert "set key autotitle columnheader" instead. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Could you please try adding following line to the example from above: "set style fill pattern" For me, it gives me: http://snag.gy/6GuW4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect colour appears to be a problem with gnuplot 4.6.0, it works in the current release version 4.6.3.

Comment: Further, the pattern problem is already known by the dev community and will be fixed in version 4.6.4 and 4.7.
Please refer to: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1258/